# How can I restrict xfce or mate setting read-only for some users (on linux mint)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, mate, xfce4

We have some PC with accounts that are shared by several users (in this case pupils). I'd like to restrict the things they can configure on the desktop environment. E.g. they should not be able to change desktop background image etc.

Is this somehow possible in xfce and / or mate (using linux mint)?

I guess I could remove write access to some config files - but for which ones? (I found that there is `~/.config/xfce4`.
I would expect that the DE needs write access to some file to function properly.

Comment: Everything that is local to the user should be under `~/.config/xfce4`. If xfce *does* need write access to a file, you could just overwrite it with a default version upon login/logout. Have you tried removing write permissions yet?

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. No, I didn't try yet, because I assumed that xfce needs write permissions. Good idea to just backup settings upon login. That should be find, I guess, thanks!

Comment: No problem! If it works you can post that as your own answer and accept it. Also, there is no harm in setting temporary user's xfce4 config read-only to see what breaks. It might just silently fail to save any changes. If it's unusable then you just have to reboot and remove that user or reverse the permissions.